# React css renders correctly only on IDE refresh

Tags: css, reactjs, visual-studio-code, material-ui

I have some unexpected CSS behaviour that I don't understand - can anyone help me understand why it's happening, and help me get my CSS imports right?

I have a react app that uses a single component, that imports a stylesheet from a separate file *brand.js*.  The component has an `<Avatar className={classes.avatarTM}>`; *brand.js* defines that class as having a backgroundColour of Dark Blue, which is what I'm expecting.

But when I load the app in Chrome, that avatar loads grey, not blue.  Inspecting the element shows that two styles apply: *.makeStyles-avatarTM-11* with the expected backgroundColor of primary.dark, and *.MUIAvatar-colorDefault* with backgroundColor #bdbdbd.  *colorDefault* takes precedence on backgroundColor over *avatarTM-11*, so I get a grey avatar.  This is not good.

If I then edit the `// deleteme` comment in *brand.js* in Visual Studio and save the file, React auto-refreshes the avatar in Chrome in Blue.  *avatarTM-11* is now taking precedence over *colorDefault*.

If I then reload the page in Chrome, it reloads as default grey.

But the bit that really screws up my attempts at bugfixing is that if I create a new file *brand2.js*, and copy/paste the exact content of *brand.js* into that new file, then modify the imports in *App2.js* and *testComponent.js* to import *brand2* instead of *brand*, it works just fine.  *avatarTM-11* now takes precedence over default no matter what loads the page, and I get a blue avatar.

So just use *brand2* instead of *brand*, right?  Right.  So I delete *brand.js*.... and the problem comes back.

What exactly is happening here?  How do I get my defined *avatarTM* style to always take precedence, no matter what is loading the page or what the stylesheet is called?  Why should the presence or absence of a file that is not being used by the app affect anything?

app2.js:

```
import React from 'react';

import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { theme } from './components/Brand';

import TestComponent from './components/testComponent';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <TestComponent />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

testComponent.js:

```
import React from 'react';

import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardHeader from '@material-ui/core/CardHeader';

import { useStyles } from './Brand';

export default function TestComponent() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <Card className={classes.card} variant="outlined">
            <CardHeader
                avatar={
                        <Avatar aria-label="testComponent" className={classes.avatarTM}>
                            t
                        </Avatar>
                }
                title="testComponent"
            />
        </Card>
    )}
```

brand.js:

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#014EAA',
      contrastText: '#ffffff',
    },
    secondary: {
      main: '#0099CC',
      contrastText: '#ffffff',
    },
    info: {
      main: '#666666',
      contrastText: '#ffffff',
    },
    error: {
      main: '#FF6600',
      contrastText: '#ffffff',
    },
    success: {
      main: '#339933',
      contrastText: '#ffffff',
    },
  },
});
// deleteme
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    color: theme.palette.primary,
    fontSize: 10,
    padding: '6px 12px',
    fontFamily: ['sans-serif']
  },
  card: {
    minwidth: 275,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 24
  },
  cardTitle: {
    fontSize: 24,
    color: theme.palette.primary.main,
  },
  cardSubtitle: {
    fontSize: 14,
    color: theme.palette.secondary.main
  },
  cardDescription: {
    fontSize: 10,
  },
  avatarTM: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.dark
  },
  avatarUnknown: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.warning.main
  },
  avatarFixed: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.light
  },
}));

export { theme, useStyles }
```

Comment: The real answer appears to depend on css specificity https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#css-injection-order.  I seem to have slightly higher specificity from the material theme than from my own makeStyles, but unfortunately I can't work out from the docs how to resolve this.  When the IDE auto-rerenders components I believe it reapplies the styles and therefore makes them more specific so they then take precedence, which explains why a code edit will temporarily resolve the issue, but not why having a second file with copy-and-paste content would work.

Answer (score -1):

You can try force this style putting property like this:

```
avatarTM: {
    backgroundColor: 'theme.palette.primary.dark !important'
},
```

Comment: This would require the !important tag on every single style defined, and would be hard to maintain.